# Отправка request в точное указанное время

Tags: python, api, requests, aiohttp, minecraft

начал писать такой вот проект, нужно чтобы моя программа посылала запрос в четко введёное мной время с максимальной точностью (например в 14:31:29). Вот мой код, в нем есть асинхронность и я не знаю как запустить эту функцию в точный момент. Пробовал с sched, но что-то не получалось. Заранее спасибо за ответы!

```
import requests
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import time


from datetime import datetime
bearer = input("Bearer Key: ")
target = input("Target Username: ")
url = 'https://api.minecraftservices.com/minecraft/profile/name/'+target
when = input('Type like this(Tue May 01 11:05:17 2018): ')

async def snipe_req():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.put(f"https://api.minecraftservices.com/minecraft/profile/name/{target}",
                               headers={"Authorization": "Bearer " + bearer,
                                        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:83.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/83.0",
                                        "Content-Type": "application/json"}) as resp:
            print(resp.status)
            print(datetime.now())
            print(await resp.text())

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(snipe_req())
```

Comment: Вам нужен метод https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.call_at

Answer (score 1):

Возможно стоит попробовать библиотеку schedule

Вот пример использования

```
import datetime, schedule, request

TIME = [('17.04.2021', '06:41:44', 'abc.php?xxx'),
    ('17.04.2021', '07:21:31', 'abc.php?yyy'),
    ('17.04.2021', '07:33:04', 'abc.php?zzz'),
    ('17.04.2021', '07:41:23', 'abc.php?www')]

def job():
    global TIME
    date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
    for i in TIME:
        runTime = i[0] + " " + i[1]
        if i and date == str(runTime):
            request.get(str(i[2]))

schedule.every(0.01).minutes.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```